# JPlayer Does Not Work On Firefox Android But All Other Browsers

Tags: javascript, android, html5-audio, jplayer

I've been trying to figure out why my jplayer configuration is playing on all browsers, except android for firefox. I followed the development guide for the last few days, and im still struggling to figure this out. My dev site is http://dev.beatautomate.com/appdevel/?uid=titus        I declared a few properties so flash will come in as a fallback back for uncompatible browsers... But Im not sure what im doing wrong.. A snippet of my code is below, and again my dev site is http://dev.beatautomate.com/appdevel/?uid=titus   any ideas, or suggestions?  thanks so much!!

```
       // json_data is a json object that has a few mp3s..

         var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist({
                jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_N",
                cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_N"
            },json_data, {
                playlistOptions: {
                    enableRemoveControls: true
                },
                swfPath: "http://www.jplayer.org/latest/js/Jplayer.swf",
                supplied: "mp3",
                smoothPlayBar: true,
                keyEnabled: true,
                solution:"flash,html"
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like jPlayer doesn't correctly detect that Firefox for Android supports MP3 playback.

Modifying all occurrences of the string 'audio/mpeg; codecs="mp3"' to 'audio/mpeg' in the jPlayer library makes playback work correctly in Firefox for Android. I'm not sure whether this creates problems for detection in any other browsers, however.

Hopefully the jPlayer team can fix this detection in the next release.